# Redirect flask request in thread

Tags: python, multithreading, redirect, flask

I need to redirect post request in another tread. But return just 200 response.
But i have no idea how can i do it

I have tried something like that, but it has no effect.
print("Redirected!") in bar() function doesn't work.

```py
from threading import Thread

from flask import Flask, redirect, Response, url_for


@app.route('/foo', methods=['POST'])
def foo():
    t = Thread(
        target=redirect,
        args = (url_for('bar'), 307)
    )
    t.start()
    t.join()
    return Response(status=200)

@app.route('/bar', methods=['POST'])
def bar():
    print("Redirected!")
    return "Redirected!"
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to resend request with everything that comes with it

```
import requests


def redirect_thread(**kwargs):
    request_funcs = {
        'GET': requests.get,
        'POST': requests.post,
        'DELETE': requests.delete,
        'PUT': requests.put
    }
    try:
        request_funcs[request.method](
            url=url,
            headers=request.headers,
            json=request.json,
            files=request.files,
            params=request.args,
            **kwargs
        )
    except KeyError:
        return jsonify({
            'error': True,
            'message': 'Method Not Allowed'
        })


@app.route('/foo', methods=['POST'])
def foo():
   t = Thread(
       target=redirect_thread(params=request.args),
   )
   t.start()
   t.join()

   return Response(status=200)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I'm a little unsure why you're manually running the redirect in another thread, joining said thread and returning the result. You should just call 'redirect()' on the original request and pass the context, which will then redirect to the '/bar' endpoint and your webserver will handle the threading.